# Conda commands not acting on current environment, Python version

Tags: python, version, conda, environment

I'm afraid I don't understand how conda works.

I have an environment with Python 3.6 installed yet every time I use the conda command it says 'Message: trial mode expires in 28 days' and says 'Please upgrade to a 2.7.x release'.

My base Python is 2.7 but I don't see why it would be referring to this inside an environment with 3.6.

```
(py36) BillsMacBookPro-9:~ billtubbs$ conda info
Vendor:  continuum
Product: anaconda
Message: trial mode expires in 28 days
/Users/billtubbs/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py:26: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a 2.7.x release that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.
  utils.DeprecatedIn23,

     active environment : py36
    active env location : /Users/billtubbs/anaconda/envs/py36
            shell level : 1
       user config file : /Users/billtubbs/.condarc
 populated config files : /Users/billtubbs/.condarc
          conda version : 4.6.3
    conda-build version : 3.10.5
         python version : 2.7.3.final.0
       base environment : /Users/billtubbs/anaconda  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/osx-64
                          https://conda.anaconda.org/conda-forge/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
          package cache : /Users/billtubbs/anaconda/pkgs
                          /Users/billtubbs/.conda/pkgs
       envs directories : /Users/billtubbs/anaconda/envs
                          /Users/billtubbs/.conda/envs
               platform : osx-64
             user-agent : conda/4.6.3 requests/2.19.1 CPython/2.7.3 Darwin/18.2.0 OSX/10.14.3
                UID:GID : 501:20
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False

(py36) BillsMacBookPro-9:~ billtubbs$ which python
/Users/billtubbs/anaconda/envs/py36/bin/python
(py36) BillsMacBookPro-9:~ billtubbs$ python --version
Python 3.6.8 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
(py36) BillsMacBookPro-9:~ billtubbs$ python
Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Dec 29 2018, 19:04:46) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Clang 4.0.1 (tags/RELEASE_401/final)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I've tried `conda update conda`.  Doesn't that update everything in the current environment?

I've also tried `conda install conda` from within this environment as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52764416/conda-command-not-available-in-conda-environment-per-default) with the following result:

```
(py36) BillsMacBookPro-9:~ billtubbs$ conda install conda
Vendor:  continuum
Product: anaconda
Message: trial mode expires in 28 days
/Users/billtubbs/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/primitives/constant_time.py:26: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Support for your Python version is deprecated. The next version of cryptography will remove support. Please upgrade to a 2.7.x release that supports hmac.compare_digest as soon as possible.
  utils.DeprecatedIn23,
Collecting package metadata: done
Solving environment: done


==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==
  current version: 4.6.2
  latest version: 4.6.3

Please update conda by running

    $ conda update -n base conda



## Package Plan ##

  environment location: /Users/billtubbs/anaconda/envs/py36

  added / updated specs:
    - conda


The following packages will be downloaded:

    package                    |            build
    ---------------------------|-----------------
    conda-4.6.3                |           py36_0         875 KB  conda-forge
    cryptography-2.5           |   py36ha12b0ac_0         590 KB
    curl-7.63.0                |    ha441bb4_1000         138 KB
    grpcio-1.16.1              |   py36h044775b_1         944 KB
    krb5-1.16.1                |       hddcf347_7         1.1 MB
    libcurl-7.63.0             |    h051b688_1000         532 KB
    libedit-3.1.20170329       |    hcfe32e1_1001         152 KB  conda-forge
    libssh2-1.8.0              |                1         256 KB  conda-forge
    pycurl-7.43.0.2            |   py36ha12b0ac_0         185 KB
    ------------------------------------------------------------
                                           Total:         4.7 MB

The following NEW packages will be INSTALLED:

  conda              conda-forge/osx-64::conda-4.6.3-py36_0
  libcurl            pkgs/main/osx-64::libcurl-7.63.0-h051b688_1000
  libedit            conda-forge/osx-64::libedit-3.1.20170329-hcfe32e1_1001

The following packages will be UPDATED:

  cryptography       conda-forge::cryptography-2.2.1-py36_0 --> pkgs/main::cryptography-2.5-py36ha12b0ac_0
  curl                           conda-forge::curl-7.60.0-0 --> pkgs/main::curl-7.63.0-ha441bb4_1000
  grpcio             conda-forge::grpcio-1.16.0-py36hd60e7~ --> pkgs/main::grpcio-1.16.1-py36h044775b_1
  krb5                           conda-forge::krb5-1.14.6-0 --> pkgs/main::krb5-1.16.1-hddcf347_7
  openssl                                 1.0.2p-h470a237_1 --> 1.1.1a-h1de35cc_1000
  pycurl                            7.43.0.1-py36hdbc3d79_0 --> 7.43.0.2-py36ha12b0ac_0
  python               conda-forge::python-3.6.6-h5001a0f_0 --> pkgs/main::python-3.6.8-haf84260_0
  sqlite                                  3.24.0-h2f33b56_0 --> 3.26.0-h1765d9f_1000
  xz                                                5.2.3-0 --> 5.2.4-h1de35cc_1001

The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:

  libssh2                                           1.8.0-2 --> 1.8.0-1


Proceed ([y]/n)? y


Downloading and Extracting Packages
pycurl-7.43.0.2      | 185 KB    | ################################### | 100% 
libssh2-1.8.0        | 256 KB    | ################################### | 100% 
conda-4.6.3          | 875 KB    | ################################### | 100% 
cryptography-2.5     | 590 KB    | ################################### | 100% 
curl-7.63.0          | 138 KB    | ################################### | 100% 
grpcio-1.16.1        | 944 KB    | ################################### | 100% 
krb5-1.16.1          | 1.1 MB    | ################################### | 100% 
libedit-3.1.20170329 | 152 KB    | ################################### | 100% 
libcurl-7.63.0       | 532 KB    | ################################### | 100% 
Preparing transaction: done
Verifying transaction: done
Executing transaction: done
Vendor:  continuum
Product: anaconda
Message: trial mode expires in 28 days
```

Maybe it's time to delete my entire conda environments and reinstall them all...

Comment: Try updating `anaconda` as well i.e. `conda update anaconda`.

Comment: Thanks @kHarsit.  I tried that.  After 13 minutes on the `Solving environment` step it says `# All requested packages already installed.`  I'm at a loss here so I think I just need to delete and reinstall this environment and maybe all others.